# fixed footer inside dynamic same sized div/columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was being looking for an answer in the internet and also in another SO questions, but none of them helped me... 
**MAIN IDEA:**
I will have divs inside the body that are dynamic (content will come from a DB), can be 3 div, can be 10 divs, can be 32 divs... those divs are a kind of thumbail, and inside it the content will also be dynamic, one div can have 4 lines of content and another can have 8, but ALL need to have the same height. Right now it is showing like this:  [image: EXAMPLE]

**WHAT I NEED**
As you can see in the image above, there is the "Categoria 1" and "Categoria 2", these need to be always in the bottom, doesn't matter how many lines the above content have, with some editing to the image, you can see what i need here: [image: EXAMPLE2]

I tried a lot of things, such position absolute and relative, display, bottom: 0px... none worked... Here's my actual code (remember that content is dynamic), please take a look and try to help me:

HTML/JS:

```
<div id="container-cursos" class="center-block container-geral-cursos">
</div>

<scrip>
                    var cursos = func.Cursos;
                    var containerCursos = $("#container-cursos");

                    for (var i = 0; i < cursos.length; i++) {
                        var curso = cursos[i];       
                        var containerCursoUnico = document.createElement("div");
                        containerCursoUnico.addClass("web-col-responsive container-div-curso");
                        containerCursos.append(containerCursoUnico);

                        var divteste = document.createElement("div");

                        var imgCurso = document.createElement("img");
                        imgCurso.addClass("img-curso-thumbnail img-responsive");
                        imgCurso.onclick = this.ClickCursoCommand.bind(this, curso);
                        imgCurso.src = shell.Host + "/content/" + curso.Imagem;

                        divteste.append(imgCurso);

                        var btnDescCurso = document.createElement("span");
                        btnDescCurso.onclick = this.ClickCursoCommand.bind(this, curso);
                        btnDescCurso.addClass("curso-titulo");
                        btnDescCurso.innerHTML = curso.Descricao;
                        divteste.append(btnDescCurso);

                        var divmodulos = document.createElement("div");
                        divModulos.addClass("NADA");
                        divModulos.style.display = "inline-block";
                        divteste.append(divModulos);


                        for (var y = 0; y < curso.Modulos.length; y++) {
                            var modulo = curso.Modulos[y];

                            var btnDescricaoModulo = document.createElement("span");
                            btnDescricaoModulo.addClass("col-xs-12 curso-modulo-descricao");
                            btnDescricaoModulo.onclick = this.ClickModuloCommand.bind(this, curso, modulo);
                            btnDescricaoModulo.innerHTML = modulo.Titulo;
                            divModulos.append(btnDescricaoModulo);
                       }
                        containerCursoUnico.append(divteste);
                        var containerCategoriaCurso = document.createElement("div");
                        containerCategoriaCurso.addClass("container-categoria-curso");                    

                        for (var j = 1; j < 3; j++) {
                            var categoriaCurso = document.createElement("span");
                            categoriaCurso.addClass("span-categoria-curso");
                            categoriaCurso.innerHTML = " Categoria " + j; 
                            containerCategoriaCurso.append(categoriaCurso);
                        }
                        containerCursoUnico.append(containerCategoriaCurso);
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.web-col-responsive {
    width: 20%;
}

    .curso-titulo {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 5px;
        background-color: #006063;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #006063;
        border-top: 2px solid #006063;
        color: white;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .curso-modulo-descricao {
        font-size: 13px;
        color: black;
        padding: 5px;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
        -moz-transition-duration: 0.4s;    
    }

    .container-geral-cursos {
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .img-curso-thumbnail {
        height: 140px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .container-categoria-curso {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .span-categoria-curso {
        font-size: 11px;
        padding: 4px;
        color: #404040;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
        -moz-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    }

    .container-div-curso {
        margin: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #006063;
        border-radius: 3px;
        box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px #8f8f8f;
        padding: 0;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
        -moz-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    }
```

**To be easier to read the code, here goes an image of the generated HTML:**
[image: GENERATED HTML]

Comment: can you show us the html generated, we cannot help you like this

Comment: ok, I'm gonna edit and post an image of the generated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flex and make `margin-top:auto` to the categories so they are pushed down. Try to add this code :

```
.container-div-curso {
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
}
.container-div-curso .container-categoria-curso {
  margin-top:auto;
}
```

Comment: i cannot believe that I didn't find a solution like this in the internet or for myself, looks so easy now... THANKS!